# mock a method calling another method using mockito, powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

-> controller.java

```
public controller() {
    public controller(DataInterpreter interpret,ControllerClientUtility util, InterfaceConnection inter) {
        interpreter = interpret;
        utility = util;
        interfaced = inter;
    }
}
```

...

```
public void closeOne(String vpnSessionId) throws Exception {
        try{
            if ( interfaced.connect() && (interfaced.CheckIntegrity(SessionId)) ){
                interfaced.kill(vpnSessionId);
            }else{
                closeAll();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            if ( e.getMessage().startsWith("INTERFACE_ERR:") ){
                closeAll();
            }else{
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

-> methods in InterfaceConnection.java

```
public String getReponseFor(String command) throws Exception{
    if (send(command)){
        return receive();
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception("INTERFACE_ERR: Could not get Response");
    }
}


public List<String> getListOfConnections() throws Exception{
   String statusResponse = getReponseFor("something");
   ..(regex searches and then make a list connectionsConnected) 
   return connectionsConnected;
}


public boolean CheckIntegrity(String SessionId){
    try {
        List<String> connections = new ArrayList<String>();
        connections = getListOfConnections();
        if (connections.contains(SessionId)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to mock the output of getListOfConnections ? I tried doing something like this but did not work

-> controllerTest.java

```
 @Mock private InterfaceConnection interfaced;

  @Before
  public void beforeTests() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    impl = new Controller(interpreter,utility,interfaced);
```

...

```
@Test
  public void testDisconnectOneSessionWithBadSessionId_sendCommand() throws Exception{
      String badSessionId = "123:123";
      List<String> mockConnections = new ArrayList<String>();
      mockConnections.add("asdasds");
      when(interfaced.getListOfConnections()).thenReturn(mockConnections);

      impl.closeOne(badSessionId);
      Mockito.verify(utility)....
 }
```

I hope I'm clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: Show all tested code and tests belonging to it. I assume that in your code you use constructor and not mock it.

Comment: How do you act on `connectionsConnected` ? How do you create this list ? When do you add `String` in it ?

Comment: getListOfConnections() actually calls another method getRepsonsefor (a method defined in InterfaceConnection), form that output i do a regex search and then return the String

Comment: Calling to 'interfaced.CheckIntegrity(SessionId)' return false and not calling method body because variable interfaced is mock. Declaring variable as mock means that it's methods wouldn't be called. Workaround - look at spy and callRealMethod

Comment: You could use a Mockito spy.  This way you can stub out `getResponseFor` while retaining the functionality of `getListOfConnections`.